# Swift searchable text did change crashes my API router

Tags: ios, swift, search, alamofire

I have a search bar in a view that works perfectly, but when I try searching a string with a space in it, my router crashes.

This is the code for the search bar text did change.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchView!.searchTextCount = count(searchText)
    if count(searchText) >= 3 {
        println("search text is \(searchText)")
        if let searchString = searchBar.text as String? {
            if count(searchString) >= 3 {
                searchView!.loadFirstSearch(searchString)
            }else {
                let emptyAlert = UIAlertController(title: "oops!", message: "search must be atleast 3 letters long", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                emptyAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(emptyAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    if count(searchText) == 0 {
        println("search text count is 0")
        searchView!.clearSearch()
    }
}
```

`searchView.loadFirstSearch(searchString)` is a function that calls my router to make the api request. searchView is the view controller that handles the search result and then places it in the `UITableview`. That part works fine. The crash happens during the API request. Here is where the error occurs.

```
   var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString + path)!
```

the second line gives me a

> "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Here are the relevant lines of code for the Router.

```
var path: String {
    case .search(let id, let pageID):
        return "/search?name=\(id)&page=\(pageID)"
```

So to help guide you guys through this code, the text didchange function calls the view controller to make an API request. The api request is handled by a wrapper, which calls Alamofire through my router. The router accepts a search String and a page number which in this instance is 1.

It takes the search string and assigns the text to "id" and places it into the path. Then the `NSURLRequest` is created with the appended path and the request is called.

The only time I get this error is when I enter a space into the search Bar, immediately when I type a space, I get the error in

```
let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString + path)!
```